# Who are the other "Unstoppables"?

Tags: fallout

In Fallout we can find series of comic books called "Unstoppables"

[image]

The barbarian in the middle is obviously Grognak and the guy with Tommy-gun is Silver Shroud.

Do we know what were the names of the other three?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They are: Silver Shroud, Mistress of Mystery, Inspector, Manta Man and Grognak the Barbarian.

As found on the Fallout wikia page describing the comics.

http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Unstoppables

Comment: Aaand... I am blind. I haven't noticed that....

Comment: i understand completely :)